# Trying to solve second equation of motion without substituting $v=(at+v_i)$

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

The derivation of $s =  s_0 + v_0t + ½at^2$ starts with $v = dx/dt$, which is rewritten as $v dt = dx$ and then $v$ is replaced with $at+v_i$.  Then it is integrated.

1. Why is this substitution done, instead of integrating $v dt = dx$ directly?  Is it to replace $v$ (not constant) with $a$ and $v_i$ (constants) and therefore make the integration easier?
2. If $v = dx/dt$ were integrated instead, would you have to use integration by parts (because $v(t)$ is not constant wrt to time)?  When I try this, I cannot get the final form of the equation ($x=x_0 +v_0t+1/2at^2$) that one gets when using the $at+v_i$ substitution. (Could be math error, but I get a $-1/2at^2$ term)

The reason I ask is because making the substitution is not intuitive to me (unless it's for #1 as stated above). Could someone explain the reason for the substitution? Could someone explain why $v = dx/dt$ can't be integrated directly? Or if it can, can you show how it's done please.

Comment: vdx=dt is wrong so it does not make any sense to integrate it.

Comment: Hi @nasu, Thanks for catching my typo - I edited the question to reflect the correct equation.

Comment: @nasu Are you familiar with Taylor Series? It may be more fundamental to view your quadratic equation for $s(t)$ as the Taylor expansion of $s(t)$ when $s''(t)$ (which = a) is constant. In that case, the equation you're seeking to derive requires no physical intuition whatsoever, it is simply a mathematical result (Taylor's Theorem) that could be applied to any function with a constant second derivative.

Comment: Boy, that is sure the hard way to do it.  Start with $x''(t)=a$ and integrate twice setting your constant of integration after each integral.

Comment: @electronpusher I am not the OP.

Comment: @nasu my mistake

Comment: The derivation starts with $d^2x/dt^2=a$ where $a$ is a constant. The textbook you are working from will explain how the formula is derived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarification, the case you are considering is for constant acceleration; that is, a is constant.  v(t) is not constant, so to evaluate $\int_{}^{}v(t) \thinspace dt$  you use $v(t) = v_i + at$ as you state.

When you integrate by parts $\int_{s_0}^{s} dx = s - s_0 =$ $\int_{0}^{t}v \enspace dt = (vt)|{_i ^f} - \int_{v_0}^{v_f}t \enspace dv$ you do obtain $-1/2 \enspace a t^2$ for the second term since dv = a dt, but **you have to evaluate the first term, vt, between the initial, i, and final, f, states**; initially, vt = 0 and finally vt = $v_ft = (v_0 + at)t $
and adding this to the second term you have $(v_0 + at)t -1/2 \enspace a t^2 = v_0t + 1/2 \enspace a t^2$

Comment: My equation is slightly different than yours.  Is my logic still correct?

Integrate $v=dx/dt$,  where $\int udv = uv - \int vdu$ (but since $v$ can be confused with velocity from the problem equation, use $\int udg = ug - \int gdu$.  

Let $u = v(t)$ ; $du = v'(t)dt$ ;  $dg = dt$ ; $g=t$ 

Substituting, $\int udg = v(t)t - \int t v'(t)dt$    (This is where I think we differ?)

$v'(t)$ is constant (constant acceleration):
$v(t)t - v'(t)\int tdt$ and $vt - 1/2 at^2 \Big|_0^t$

Substitute $v=v_0+at$ & get $v_0t+1/2at^2$

Comment: That works.  Note tv' dt = t (dv/dt) dt = t dv.  So your integral and mine are the same in the second terms using integration by parts.